# DirectX rendering Transparency

Tags: directx, sharpdx

When i draw cubes over DirectX (SharpDX wrapper) i get the next behaviour:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplJ1.png)
From one side i see pipe laying inside cubes and i do not see back cubes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5gpq.png)
From the other side i see back cubes and pipe.
There is a code by which i initialize depth buffer:

```
    private void InitializeDepthBuffer() {

      var depthStencilDesc = new DepthStencilStateDescription {
        IsDepthEnabled = true,
        DepthWriteMask = DepthWriteMask.All,
        DepthComparison = Comparison.Always,
        IsStencilEnabled = false
      };

      var depthStencilState = new DepthStencilState(_device3D, depthStencilDesc);
      _context3D.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState);

      var depthBufferDesc = new Texture2DDescription {
        Width = Width,
        Height = Height,
        ArraySize = 1,
        MipLevels = 1,
        Format = Format.D24_UNorm_S8_UInt,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
        BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
      };

      var depthBuffer = new Texture2D(_device3D, depthBufferDesc);

      var depthStencilViewDesc = new DepthStencilViewDescription {
        Format = depthBufferDesc.Format,
        Dimension = DepthStencilViewDimension.Texture2D
      };

      _depthStencilView = new DepthStencilView(_device3D, depthBuffer, depthStencilViewDesc);
      _context3D.OutputMerger.SetTargets(_depthStencilView, _renderTargetView);
    }
```

and inside RenderLoop I do:

```
_context3D.ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
```

I want to delete transparency. But i do not know direction in which to move. Please, help

I want to avoid transparency